# How do you install an ASUS USB-AC56 on Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, wireless, software-installation, asus, realtek-wireless

I'm trying to get this ASUS USB-AC56 adapter installed on Ubuntu 16.04, but when I try to extract the Linux file from the cd, it says I don't have the right permissions to extract.

I've tried the indications that were given in the post "How do I install an ASUS USB-AC56 Wifi adapter?", but at the command line
sudo modprobe 8812au

I get

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module 8812au not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-70-generic
```

At the command line

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
```

The installation doesn't seem to compleate, since at one stage, I get the message

```
Building module:
cleaning build area....
'make' all....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/rtl8812au-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.4.0-171-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/make.log for more information.
   ...done.
```

Could anybody help me with the installation?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use [the provided package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/rtl8812au-dkms) for RTL8812AU?

Comment: The driver on the cd is obsolete and won't build. Install `rtl8812au-dkms`

Comment: Ok, so what must I do to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Slight update,
I have tried the tips provided in the post "Installing Asus USB-AC56 Adapter on Ubuntu 17.10", the installation goes well, but the driver doesn't seem to be working much better (Its light doesn't light up). Thanks for your help.